# Hiding some elements based on observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of objects like this

```
   function Person(id,name,age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    var listOfPeople = [
        new Person(1, 'Fred', 25),
        new Person(2, 'Joe', 60),
        new Person(3, 'Sally', 43)
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        people: ko.observableArray(listOfPeople),
        selectedPeople: ko.observableArray([1])
    };


    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I would like to build a list of checkboxes, one for each person. It's working fine till this point.

Now my confusion is how to enable only the specific check boxes present in some array, similar to selected people.

I tried this code, it's not working

```
  <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedPeople, enable:$parent.selectedPeople" ><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an another property let say `enabled` to do this. You can try something like this,

```js
function Person(id, name, age) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var listOfPeople = [
  new Person(1, 'ABC', 25),
  new Person(2, 'BCD', 60),
  new Person(3, 'CDE', 43)
];

var viewModel = {
  people: ko.observableArray(listOfPeople),
  selectedPeople: ko.observableArray([1]),
  activePeople: ko.observableArray([1, 3]),
  isEnabled: function(id) {
    return this.activePeople().some(function(activeId) {
      return activeId === id;
    });
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedPeople, enable: $parent.isEnabled(id)"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get the view model from server, So, is there any way to do it in KO itself?

Comment: Why cant you attach a property `enabled` with the Model after getting it from server.

Comment: I would suggest the knockout mapping plug-in to re-create Persons with an additional property rather than looping through each Person and adding a property.

Comment: In this scenario, `ko.mapping` is not required as it would create each property as an `observable`. If the `person` object has to be updated with UI as well as with model, then we can go with `ko.mapping`.

Comment: That's not correct always. The mapping plugin by default create them as observables if you are not specifying a custom `create` callback to the mapper. You can choose to refrain from creating properties as observables wherever you don't want the two way binding. Have a look @ the `Customizing object construction using “create”` article in the documentation here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and as an example you can look at my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mhaho5dc/11/...

Comment: I have an observablearray called isEnabled that contains id's of persons. Is there any way I can disable the list elements based on this array?

I'm not allowed to add any property to the view model

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the value of a property to be equal to that of the same property in the `selectedPeople` object, and use this equality to `enable` or `disable` as you may require like below -

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: selectedPeople().ifSelected, enable: selectedPeople().ifSelected === ifSelected"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can notice an additional `boolean` property `ifSelected` in the `Person` object, which is being used here for this equality purpose. However, this comparison should be of any sort (string, range, number equality, etc.), but it should be evaluated to a bool.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhaho5dc/2/)

**EDIT**

After looking at your comment that you are getting the data from the server, here is how you can create a custom `Persons` class with an additional `ifEnabled` property to handle whether a `checkbox` is `enable` or not.

```
function Persons(data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data !== null) {
      self.name = data.name;
      self.id = data.id;
      self.age = data.age;
      // only below properties are observables.
      self.ifSelected = ko.observable(false);
      // below comparison will decide which check box to enable.
      self.ifEnabled = ko.observable(self.age > 50);
    }
}
```

Now, as mentioned in my comment for the other answer here, you can use the knockout's mapping plugin to insert that additional property into the `Person` object like so -

```
var mappingOptions = {
    create: function(options) {
      return new Persons(options.data);
    }
};
```

As you can see, this is how you can create observables as you want and leave those as plain values that you don't want to be mapped into an observable.

And finally, below piece of code creates the desired `people` array for your binding -

```
var persons = ko.mapping.fromJS(listOfPeople, mappingOptions);    
self.people = ko.observableArray(persons());
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhaho5dc/11/)